# is it possible to receive more information from a query by using Xpath in PHP than just one? (-nodeValue)

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Hoi,

for example, i have a xml file :

> ```
> <bookstore>
>
> <book category="COOKING">
>   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
>   <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
>   <year>2005</year>
>   <price>30.00</price>
> </book>
>
> <book category="WEB">
>   <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
>   <author>James McGovern</author>
>   <author>Per Bothner</author>
>   <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
>   <author>James Linn</author>
>   <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
>   <year>2003</year>
>   <price>49.99</price>
> </book>
>
> </bookstore>
> ```

**And I want all the *titles* and *prices***

**I could write this code**

```
<php
$res = $xpath->query('/bookstore/book/title');
foreach ($res as $item) {
  echo "{$item->nodeValue}";
}  
$res = $xpath->query('/bookstore/book/price');
foreach ($res as $item) {
  echo "{$item->nodeValue}";
}  
?>
```

But this looks very ugly,
Is there another possibility so that I can combine those 2 blocks of code?

something like this?

```
<php
$res = $xpath->query('/bookstore/book');
foreach ($res as $item) {
  echo "{$item->title} <br/> {$item->price}";
}  
?>
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust your XPATH with concatenate to read '/bookstore/book/title **|** /bookstore/book/price'
This would give you a node list as such:

```
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<price>30.00</price>
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<price>49.99</price>
...
...
```

Then just pull values 1 and 2 in each foreach loop cycle for what you like.

Hope this helps!